# Main difference between GET and POST api calls?

Tags: api, flask

I am getting confused with the difference with GET and POST.
Can you provide some good resource or explanation with examples.
I'm just getting started with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Hope this clears things out for you https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/

Answer (score 1):

GET is for retrieving data from the URL - for example, example.com?tab=settings

'tab' is what you would use to 'GET' the data from

POST is more secure, and allows you to send or retrieve the data directly

Other points mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) are:

```
GET requests can be cached
GET requests remain in the browser history
GET requests can be bookmarked
GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
GET requests have length restrictions
GET requests are only used to request data (not modify)


POST requests are never cached
POST requests do not remain in the browser history
POST requests cannot be bookmarked
POST requests have no restrictions on data length
```